# Disable tooltip text if button is disabled in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, syncfusion

I'm new to UI, I have requirement for my angular application, where my button will be enabled and disabled on some conditions. I want to show tooltip only if button is enabled, I'm able to change cursor type on enable/disabled button, but want to know how can I enable the tooltip text only if my button is enabled, below is my code.

```
<button ejs-button type="button" (click)="formulabuilder(data) [attr.disabled]="data.disable==true?'':null"  
        title="Formula Builder" class="formula_builder_btn">
    <mat-icon role="img" class="mat-icon material-icons mat-icon-no-color"> apps</mat-icon>
</button>

.formula_builder_btn:disabled {
  cursor: default;
}

.formula_builder_btn{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Is am I doing anything wrong? how can I achieve this.

Comment: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/tooltip/how-to/show-tooltip-on-disabled-elements-and-disable-tooltip/ - Does this help ? The idea would be give the tooltip an if condition same as the condition given to the button. Adding disabled attribute dynamically to the tooltip with the same condition given to button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally add the title

```
<button ejs-button type="button" title="{{ data.disable? '' : 'Formula Builder'}}">
```

Comment: better use "null" `title="{{data.disable?null:'Formula Builder'}}"` -If you use null, the attribute has no render-

Answer (score 0):

We have checked your reported requirement, we can achieve your requirement using CSS styles.  We have set the pointer event as none for the disabled element (button) through CSS. Please refer to code snippets.

> <button ejs-button [isPrimary]="true" [disabled]="true" title="Formula
> Builder">Primary
>
> .e-btn:disabled {   pointer-events: none; }

For your reference, we have prepared a sample based on this, please refer to below link.

Link:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zcgd11-qjzzns?file=app.component.css

Please let us know if you need any further assistance.

Regards,
Mohan kumar R